# Mcelog Doesn't Work - openSUSE

Tags: mcelog

I am trying to use mcelog in openSUSE. The proble is that while it is installed the command `sudo mcelog --client` does nothing, there is no `/var/log/mcelog` and `systemctl status mcelog` I get:

```
● mcelog.service - Machine Check Exception Logging Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mcelog.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-01-11 19:13:00 EET; 1h 14min ago
  Process: 1096 ExecStartPre=/sbin/modprobe msr (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1115 (mcelog)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mcelog.service
           └─1115 /usr/sbin/mcelog --ignorenodev --daemon --foreground

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

What is happening?